# Prove that $A^3-3A^2+4A-5=0$ for a given matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following matrix $A$:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &-1\\
1 &1 &1\\
-1 &0 &2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\text{Prove that }\;A^3-3A^2+4A-5=0$$

I have *no* idea how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use Cayley Hamilton Theorem

Comment: You probably mean $-5I$. For the rest I guess it's just working out matrix products.

Comment: @SPK It just says 5 in the problem.

Comment: What did you try? There is nothing there to solve, just compute $A^2=A\cdot A, A^3=A^2\cdot A$ and so on, and put it into the equation, check if it gives zero.

Comment: Does it have anything with diagonalization of a matrix?

Comment: @Nash: Then the question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It just seems like a lot of work to do that. I am wondering if there is a simpler more efficient way to solve it i.e. digonal matrix?

Comment: @SPK I guess the teacher has made a mistake. Lets say it is -5I

Comment: @Nash If it just says $\;5\;$ in the problem then that is either an agreed on notation when dealing with matrix equations or else, and most probably, a rather ugly though-not-so-terrible mistake.

Comment: The simpler way is, as the first comment says, to apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Nash: do you know about the characteristic polynomial of a (square) matrix and about Cayley-Hamilton theorem, as mentioned before?

Comment: @Timbuk I am sorry. I have never heard of that. I am googling now to find out more about it :) Thanks

Comment: WOW. I had never seen this theorem before! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Nash: FYI, this matrix is *not* diagonalizable. The eigenvalue $2$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric multiplicity only $1$. (I'm not sure if you've learned yet what these mean.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. I have but not so well. I still get confused.

Comment: If that's true (that you've never seen the Cayley-Hamilton theorem before) you shouldn't use the theorem in your problem solution.  It's probably not the intent of the problem. Instead, just compute it directly.  The hardest part of the problem is computing $A^3$; along the way you compute $A^2$ and so evaluating the polynomial is a matter of linear combination.  For a $3\times 3$ matrix in which all of the entries are 0, 1, -1, or 2, it's not going to take you too much time.  Less time than asking this question, even!

Comment: Is this problem correct?

Comment: @Nash, then I'm afraid there is no way out of doing the matrices' products and stuff...BTW, the identity you have to "prove" is false, since using Cayley Hamilton I get $$A^3-3A^2=4I\implies A^3-3A^2+4A-5I=4A-I$$

Comment: I get a weird result too but not that what you got

Comment: @Nash As long as you don't show your work (in the question itself after editing, if you want), we cannot be sure whether you did or not a mistake.

Comment: You are totally right. Sorry. I get $2x^2-x-4$ for the char. polynomial

Comment: @Nash In the above it should be $$A^3-3A^2=-4I\implies A^3-3A^2+4A-5I=4A-9I$$ very different still from zero.

Comment: $-x((1-x)2-0)-1(2+1)-1(0+(1-x)$ Is this right for the char. pol.?

Comment: @Nash The characteristic polynomial of **any** matrix equals its order. A $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix has a cubic char. polynomial.

Comment: The matrix $A$ does not satisfy the equation above. $A$ has eigenvalues $-1,2,2$ so the characteristic polynomial is $x^3-3x^2+4$.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is wrong. If one evaluates it all, one gets a very non-zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Simply verify that $(A\cdot A \cdot A) - 3(A\cdot A) + 4A - 5I = 0$, where I here denotes the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, and $0$ is the $3\times3$ zero matrix.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simpler faster way to do this? Maybe with a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. Do you have any idea you would like to apply, but are perhaps unsure of?

Comment: In light of Ted Shifrin's answer you might want to insert "if" after "calculate".

Comment: I changed it to "verify" instead of "calculate". Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to do this as $A$ does **not** satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, which is

$$q(x)=-x^3+3x^2-4$$

then divide the given polynomial $p(x)=x^3-3x^2+4x-5$ by the characteristic polynomial to get the remainder

$$p(x)=q(x)a(x)+r(x)$$

The remainder will have smaller degree. Since by Hamilton-Cayley the characteristic polynomial vanishes when evaluated at the matrix we get

$$p(A)=q(A)a(A)+r(A)=r(A)$$

then compute $r(A)$.

In our case $$p(x)=-q(x)+4x-9$$

Therefore $$p(A)=4A-9$$

So to evaluate the polynomial at $A$, we just need to multiply that matrix by $4$ and subtract later $9$ in the diagonal.

Comment: What is $p(x)$?

Comment: @Ale "that polynomial". The one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply $A$ repeatedly starting at the second basis vector $e_2$ (which looked most promising to me) you get $(0,1,0)\overset{A}\mapsto(1,1,0)\overset{A}\mapsto(1,2,-1)\overset{A}\mapsto(3,2,-3)$. The first three vectors are clearly linearly independent and form a basis. The fourth one satisfies $(3,2,-3)=-4(0,1,0)+3(1,2,-1)$. Therefore $P=X^3-3X^2+4$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial such that $P[A](e_2)=0$. Since $P[A]$ also kills $A(e_2)$ and $A^2(e_2)$, it is actually the minimal (and characteristic) polynomial of $A$. Since it does not divide the given polynomial $X^3-3X^2+4X-5$, that polynomial evaluated in $A$ is not zero.